# Angular : why this ng-if doesn't work?

Tags: angular

I have this code in my app :

Template :

```
  <ng-container ng-if="cpt < 3">
    {{cpt}}
    <button pButton type="button" (click)="incrementCpt()" label="+"></button>
  </ng-container>
```

Component :

```
public cpt: number = 0;
...
  incrementCpt() {
    this.cpt++;
  }
```

But the button is never hidden. I don't understand why?

Answer (score 2):

if should be `*ngIf` instead of `ng-if`

Answer (score 0):

```
<button pButton type="button" (click)="incrementCpt().bind(this)" label="+"></button>
```

have you tried that too ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not use `*` with `ngIf`
Use like this

```
*ngIf="cpt < 3"
```

Comment: you answer is correct but the statement because of * is partially correct

Comment: Ohkkkk ..but * is also important for ngIf in angular 2